# Can’t you just knock a prophecy off the shelves and smash it to hear what it says in the Department of Mysteries?

Tags: harry-potter, order-of-the-phoenix

In *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*, there’s a point in the Department of Mysteries where two prophecies get smashed and are able to be heard. But these two prophecies are not about anybody present.

Couldn’t one of the Death Eaters do this for the prophecy about Harry and Voldemort? Just smash the prophecy off the shelf and listen to it?

Comment: I closed this question as a [duplicate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) of the linked question, as it seems to be fundamentally asking the same thing. If it's not, you can [edit] to clarify.